# When building image for simple Golang Application go.mod file is missing

Tags: docker, go

I am using Docker Desktop on Windows following a [simple tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/complete-guide-to-create-docker-container-for-your-golang-application-80f3fb59a15e) on creating a docker application for a golang web server.

Given the code:

```
package main

import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })
    r.Run(":3000")
}
```

And Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:alpine

# Set necessary environmet variables needed for our image
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64

# Move to working directory /build
WORKDIR /build

# Copy and download dependency using go mod
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

# Copy the code into the container
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN go build -o main .

# Move to /dist directory as the place for resulting binary folder
WORKDIR /dist

# Copy binary from build to main folder
RUN cp /build/main .

# Export necessary port
EXPOSE 3000

# Command to run when starting the container
CMD ["/dist/main"]
```

When building the image using:

```
docker build . -t go-dock
```

I get:

[image]

Why is this the case?

Comment: [Don't paste images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial is skipping a step of using go modules

One option is to remove these lines

```
# Copy and download dependency using go mod
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download
```

and replace it with

```
RUN go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

The other more recommended option is to stick with the go modules approach in which you will need to run

```
go mod init
```

Then add this line to the bottom of your go.mod file which should have been generated from the above command

```
require github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.5.0
```

Here is the tutorials example of his go.mod file https://github.com/afdolriski/golang-docker/blob/master/go.mod

To create the go.sum file this is created when you do.

```
go build
```

I believe you could skip the creating go.sum if you remove this line from the dockerfile

```
COPY go.sum .
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer